# validate onchange event for textbox for decimal values and integers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the OnChange event for textbox to not to call for similar values like 7 and 7.000. 
I know a way to do this is by setting data attribute but this way I have to keep changing the data attribute for each newly entered value in the textbox.

Is there any work around to solve this and not call the OnChange event for similar values provided?

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: Hadn't tried right now. Have a requirement in which a textbox field is there and onchange of that I am calculating something picking the value. I need to restrict the calculation being called twice for 7 and 7.000.

Comment: Here is the illustration for my requirement in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dd8u4un8/